# Intraday volatility pattern of Emini

Tags: volatility, futures, standard-deviation, intraday

I have the series of 1-min logarithmic returns of Emini future from 2007 to 2020

I calculated the standard deviation of each return at a fixed time of day and then I plotted the results (see image).

I have some difficulties explaining what I see:
First, I notice that volatility is highest from 9:30 to 16:00, when the US market is open.

I cannon justify those spikes at some fixed time, like 10:00, 10:30, 15:45, 15:50 and 15:59.
Are those related to some macroeconomic news?
I tried to remove those days when the most important macroeconomic news are released (PPI, CPI, Employment), but the spikes remain...

Also, what is the origin of the similar pattern (at a smaller scale) from 3:00 AM to 8:30? (I suppose is related to the opening of the European market).

Any thoughts or insight is much appreciated

[image: Emini volatility pattern]

Comment: Please specify if the times you used are Chicago Time or New York Time (there is a 1 hour difference). The NYSE opens at 8:30 Chicago or 9:30 New York.

Comment: There are US announcements both at 8:30 am Eastern Time (such as Unemployment, which you eliminated) and at 10am ET (such as leading indicators, for ex). Some companies release earnings at 16:00, immediately after the NYSE close. You are probably right about the European anncmts, those are somewhat irregular in schedule IIRC. There is also a temporary halt in emini trading from 4:15 to 4:30 and from 5pm to 6pm which might explain the zero vol ;)

Comment: The U shaped pattern of volatility while the NYSE is open is absolutely classic and well known in the literature.

Comment: Given the proportion of daily activity that occurs in the final hour (or half hour), higher vol during that period doesn't seem surprising.

Comment: DAX opens in Frankfurt 9am CET, which is (usually) 3am Eastern Time in US. So another match :)

Comment: @noob2 thanks a lot! Can you please better explain what are these "leading indicators" at 10am?

Comment: There are some announcements at 10am, Leading Indicator Index is just one example of such a 10am announcement, it comes out sometime after the 15th of the month. It is not particularly noteworthy TBH, it is just the 1st 10am announcement I thought about. https://conference-board.org/data/bciarchive.cfm?cid=1 You can look here for other 8:30 or 10:00 am announcements https://www.marketwatch.com/economy-politics/calendar